# Redirect with wildcard-matching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes

I am renaming the `/widgets` route in my app to `/thingers`, and I'd like to be able to redirect all `widget`-related URLs to their `thinger` counterparts with a single line.

Something like:

```
get '/widgets(*anything)', to: redirect('/thinger%{anything}'), 
    as: 'widgets_redirect'
```

^^^That does not work: it passes slashes through as `%2F30%2F`, and doesn't pass file extensions at all.

The only working solution I have is in several lines:

```
get '/widgets', to: redirect('/thingers'), as 'widgets_redirect'
get '/widgets/:id', to: redirect('/thingers/%{id}')
get '/widgets/:id/:action.:ext', to: redirect('/thingers/%{id}/%{action}.%{ext}')
get '/widgets/:id/:action', to: redirect('/thingers/%{id}/%{action}')
```

*edit: Swapped the last two lines, otherwise the one without the file extension matches and incorrectly handles requests with extensions.

How can I cover all those cases with a single line?

Answer (score 2):

The . character is defined in ActionController::Routing::SEPARATORS, which lists special characters to split the URL on. This is why all your extensions are getting cut off.

If you want to avoid splitting the URL at .s, you need to pass a :constraints => { :yourvalue => /regexp/ } argument

You can try this to redirect all your links with the extension as well :

These two routes will give you what you are trying to achieve :

```
get '/widget', to: redirect('/thingers')
get 'widget/:thingy', to: redirect('/thingers/%{thingy}'), :constraints => { :thingy => /.*/ }
```

Comment: Why doesn't `/.*/` include slashes also?

Comment: It does. Any link that you now write for ex: `/widget/something/another.txt` will be redirected to `/thingers/something/another.txt`

Comment: Unfortunately it hasn't: slashes are still URL-encoded rather than passed through, so for `/widgets/info.json` I am redirected to `/thingers30%2Finfo.json`.  I would also like to know why your solution needs two lines if slashes can be matched - why not just `redirect('/thingers%{thingy}')` ?